# Flutter redux: How to clear state on logout in and reinitialise on login

Tags: redux, flutter, flutter-redux

I am new to flutter and have implemented the redux development pattern in the mobile application. On logout I wish to clear the state of the flutter app. Else if Participant 1 logs in and Participant 2 logs in Participant 2 views the data of Participant 1 as the data is cached. So once Participant 1 logs in the state of the app should be reinitialised. 
I have three state objects 
1. Authstate
2. UIState

I am current doing this in app_reducer.dart

```
if(action is UserLogout) { return AppState().rebuild((b) => b.authState.replace(state.authState)); }
```

My logout action is UserLogout and Login is UserLogin.

Comment: You can clear the data when you dispatch `UserLogout` and initialize it when you dispatch `UserLogin` I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: What is the code to clear in flutter is it like this=> if(action is UserLogout) {
    return AppState().rebuild((b) => b.authState.replace(state.authState));
  }

Comment: Can you add your code? so I can help!

Comment: @Taym Added the code above.